# How to enable extension in magento 2.2.6?

Tags: magento2.2.6

How to enable extension in magento2.2.6?
Please check this screenshot.
http://prntscr.com/lho9r8

Comment: why you used cron to enable extension ?

Comment: There is no need to set up cron to enable the extension. You can simply connect to the server using SSH and run the commands mentioned by @kishan-patadia from the document root of your Magento.

Comment: public_html/php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Mageplaza_Productslider
like this?
prntscr.com/lhoud1

Comment: Please let know another way for enable extension like admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect by SSH and run below commands

```
php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Namespace_Module
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: #0 4 * * * find /home/213836.cloudwaysapps.com/ehanwfcbkq/public_html/php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Mageplaza_Productslider> /dev/null 2>&1
#0 4 * * * find /home/213836.cloudwaysapps.com/ehanwfcbkq/public_html/php bin/magento setup:upgrade> /dev/null 2>&1
#0 4 * * * find /home/213836.cloudwaysapps.com/ehanwfcbkq/public_html/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Now Its ok? please let me know

Comment: Are you writing that line of code in cron job ?

Comment: yes Please check this screenshot http://prntscr.com/lhofxb.

Comment: But why you are writing it in cron ?

Comment: ok then please let me know where i run these commend?

Comment: Connect by SSH and run command as I mentioned in my answer in terminal.

Comment: Please check this link http://prntscr.com/lhokrz. how to increase time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85684/discussion-between-neha-rani-and-kishan-patadia).

Comment: please check now what is the issue now http://prntscr.com/lhoq6d.